# Rails has_many :through Find by Extra Attributes in Join Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, has-many-through

New to both Ruby and Rails but I'm book educated by now (which apparently means nothing, haha).

I've got two models, Event and User joined through a table EventUser

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :events, :through => :event_users
end

class EventUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

  #For clarity's sake, EventUser also has a boolean column "active", among others
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_users
  has_many :users, :through => :event_users
end
```

This project is a calendar, in which I have to keep track of people signing up and scratching their name out for a given event. I figure the many to many is a good approach, but I can't do something like this:

```
u = User.find :first
active_events = u.events.find_by_active(true)
```

Because events don't actually HAVE that extra data, the EventUser model does.  And while I could do:

```
u = User.find :first
active_events = []
u.event_users.find_by_active(true).do |eu|
  active_events << eu.event
end
```

This seems to be contrary to "the rails way".  Can anyone enlighten me, this has been bugging me for a long time tonight (this morning)?

Comment: You could also create a named scope using Gareth's suggestion.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

How about adding something like this into your User model?

```
has_many  :active_events, :through => :event_users, 
          :class_name => "Event", 
          :source => :event, 
          :conditions => ['event_users.active = ?',true]
```

After that you should be able to get active events for a user just by calling:

```
User.first.active_events
```

Comment: I've marked you up, but if I don't get a better answer by morning it's yours.

Comment: See my answer below for a more up-to-date method

Comment: Thanks, Rails 4 way is: `-> { where event_users: { active: true } }`

Comment: But there is no chance that the condition would be defined by a `event_users` scope? Like `scope :active, where(:active => true)`? (using Rails 3.2)

Comment: @IvanBlack could you explain where that would fit in with `has_many through:`? Could you include the whole Rails 4 specific equivalent?

Comment: @DamienRoche, `->{where...}` instead of `:conditions`. [full version](http://gist.github.com/logrusorgru/23f67ed331d13a4ebfae)

Answer (score 23):

Milan Novota has a good solution – but `:conditions` is now deprecated and the `:conditions => ['event_users.active = ?',true]` bit just doesn't seem very rails anyways. I prefer something like this:

```
has_many :event_users
has_many :active_event_users, -> { where active: true }, class_name: 'EventUser'
has_many :active_events, :through => :active_event_users, class_name: 'Event', :source => :event
```

After that you should still be able to get active events for a user just by calling:

```
User.first.active_events
```

Comment: If you're not yet on Rails 4, you can still follow this excellent example, but you may need to use the deprecated `:conditions => {active: true}`.  Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Even though your u.events isn't *explicitly* calling the user_events table, that table is still included in the SQL *implicitly* because of the necessary joins. So, you can still use that table in your find conditions:

```
u.events.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_events.active = ?", true])
```

Of course, if you plan to be doing this lookup a lot then sure, give it a separate association as Milan Novota suggests, but there's no *requirement* for you to do it that way

Comment: I like to define all the scopes at one place - in the model, even if I use them just once. It keeps my controllers thin and the overall design more consistent.

Answer (score 9):

Well, more responsibility is being put in `User` model than actually needed, and there is no good reason to do so.

We can first define the scope in `EventUser` model because where it actually belongs, like:

```
class EventUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user

  scope :active,   -> { where(active: true)  }
  scope :inactive, -> { where(active: false) } 
end
```

Now, a user could have both kind of events: active events as well as inactive events, so we can define the relationship in `User` model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_event_users,   -> { active },   class_name: "EventUser"
  has_many :inactive_event_users, -> { inactive }, class_name: "EventUser"

  has_many :inactive_events, through: :inactive_event_user,
                             class_name: "Event",
                             source: :event
  has_many :active_events,   through: :active_event_users,
                             class_name: "Event",
                             source: :event
end
```

The beauty in this technique is that the functionality of being an active or an inactive event belongs to `EventUser` model, and if in future the functionality needs to be modified, it would be modified only in one place: `EventUser` model, and the changes will be reflected in all other models.

Comment: your solution made my day :)