# rails has_many :through - Is it possible to have a conditions in the through table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

There are 2 models, and they are linked using a has_many :though relation.

There is the :conditions parameter, that will look for a condition in the other model table, but is there someway to create a condition in the join table?

For example, supose I have:

```
User
Game
GameUser
```

One User may have many games, as a Game may have many users.
But i want to store extra information in the joint table, for example if the user likes or not that game.

And I would like to have a relation filter in my User model, something like this:

```
has_many :games, :through => 'game_users'   
has_many :liked_games, :through => 'game_users', :conditions_join => { :like => true }
```

Is there a pretty way to have this functionality?

Comment: Seems to be related to this question, which has a good answer => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails has\_many :through Find by Extra Attributes in Join Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model)

Answer (score 38):

Jochen's link has a good solution – but `:conditions` is deprecated and the `:conditions => ['event_users.active = ?',true]` bit just doesn't seem very rails. Try this:

```
has_many :game_users
has_many :game_likes, -> { where like: true }, class_name: 'GameUser'
has_many :liked_games, :through => :game_likes, class_name: 'Game', :source => :game
```

Comment: Bear in mind that answer is from 2009 (the linked answer). `:conditions => ['event_users.active = ?',true]` was how things were done before Rails 3.

Comment: I'm not criticizing, just trying to provide an up-to-date answer for anyone who finds their way here looking for one

Comment: it there a way to do this without explicitly defining `game_likes`?, i mean just with conditions on `liked_games`

Answer (score 19):

In Rails 4 you can do:

```
# app/models/user.rb

has_many :liked_games, -> { where(like: true) }, class_name: "Game", 
  through: :game_users, source: :game
```

Comment: the question is how to create record with this condition using simple_form

Comment: What is the use of `:source` attribute?

Comment: Rails doesn't know which field to use on the `game_users` table to make the association with, since `liked_games` doesn't match any foreign keys on the `game_users` table. So you have to tell it to use the `game_id` field by specifying `source: :game`.