# Find by intermediary attribute in a has_many :through in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, relationships

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails has_many :through Find by Extra Attributes in Join Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model)

I have the following many to many setup in my model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projectcollaborations
  has_many :partners, :through => :projectcollaborations, :source => :partner
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projectcollaborations
  has_many :projects, :through => :projectcollaborations, :source => :project
end

class Projectcollaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :partner
end
```

I can access:

```
@partner = Partner.first
@partner.projects
@partner.projectcollaborations.find_by_myrole('creator')
....
```

now how can I access the `@partner`'s all project having myrole creator in my many-to-many relationship table?

Comment: Please use correct casing for your association and class names: i.e `project_collaborations`, not `projectcollaborations` and `ProjectCollaboration`, not `Projectcollaboration`. This makes you code much more readable for all involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
@collaborations = @partner.projectcollaborations.includes(:projects).find_all_by_myrole('creator')
@projects = @collaborations.map &:project
```

maybe there is another, prettier, railsier way, but this is how i'd do it