# Multiple Has Many Through One Relationships Pointing to Same Models - Getting data out in ruby

Tags: ruby, has-many-through

I have two separate has many through one relationships pointing to the same objects.

- Users have many photos through photo_relationships
- Users have many photos through votes

In my controller I'm trying to show all of the photos for the user through this code:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@photos = @user.photos
```

However, the Inner Join is being controlled by whatever has_many relationships is mentioned last in the User model, in this case votes. Is there a way to specify what inner join is used such as:

```
@photos = @user.photos( joins: :photo_relationships)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
class User
  ...
  has_many :voted_photos,        class_name: 'Photo', through: :votes
  has_many :relationship_photos, class_name: 'Photo', through: :photo_relationships
end
```

Comment: Thanks much! I added a source: :photo onto the code as well, this allowed me to leave the other models alone. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model) also helped me once you got me going in the right direction.