# Access join model data in has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have a many to many association such as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :working_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :working_groups

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :working_groups
  has_many :users, :through => :working_groups

class WorkingGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
```

And the Working_Groups association has some additional info about each relationship (such as order and type of membership):

```
create_table "working_groups", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.string   "role"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
```

In the user view, I'm trying to display a list of all the groups the user belong toand their type of membership (which is stored in the join table). The only way I found to get this done is something like this, that looks extremely ugly and not the most efficient thing ever...

Name
        Role

Is there a better way to do this? There must be a better way...

Comment: Very similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model?rq=1

Comment: That actually solved my question, so closing this one, thanks!