# Rails has_many through condition context

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three model `Role`, `Action` and `RoleAction` with some code:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :actions, -> {where role_actions:{status: 1}}, :through => :roleActions
    has_many :actions, :through => :roleActions #other context(manager, etc...)
    has_many :roleActions
end

class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :actions, foreign_key: 'parent_id'
    has_many :roleActions
    has_many :roles, through: :roleActions
end

class RoleAction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role
    belongs_to :action
end
```

When I using `role.actions` will get actions of `role` and have `status == 1` in role_actions.

But I want to when I using `role.actions("manager")` (with "manager" is context name) will return all action of role.

How can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408872/rails-has-many-through-find-by-extra-attributes-in-join-model

Comment: You could do it with `role.actions.where(name_of_attribute: 'manager')`. Where name_of_attribute is the attribute name in which your storing "manager" value

Answer (score 1):

> 1. You need to keep your associations `snake_case`
> 2. You cannot have multiple associations with the same name (IE `actions`)

---

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/models/role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :role_actions
   has_many :actions, through: :role_actions do
      def status(val)
        { where status: val } # @role.actions.status(1)
      end
   end
end

#app/models/role_action.rb
class RoleAction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :role
   bleongs_to :action
end

#app/models/action.rb
class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :role_actions
   has_many :actions, through: :role_actions
end
```

You'll want to look up [scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html) in Rails - it's bad practice to define conditions in your association query, only to then want to break it. Some would call it an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

--

If you have the "naked" assocation, you'll be able to scope that however you want. You can also use [ActiveRecord association extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) to provide specific functionality on your association itself (as demonstrated above).

> `role.actions("manager")`

This can be achieved by simply invoking the `Role` object when looking up the *manager* value:

```
@role = Role.find_by name: "manager"
@role.actions #-> all actions for the "manager" role.
```